# Appending value to attribute name

Tags: javascript, arrays, attr

I am trying to set attributes to a JavaScript model.
I want to add the name as logo0, logo1, logo2 for each loop.
The below code snippet line is wrong logo+[i].

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= paths.length - 1; i++) {
  Polygon.attr({
        logo+i: {
          d: paths[i],
          stroke: 'red',
          strokeWidth: "15",
          cursor: 'pointer',
          event: 'element:path-click',
          strokeLinecap: "square"
        }
      });
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: what's Polygon?

Comment: Its a modal. I just need for each loop the logo is appended by values 0 , 1 .

Comment: I didn't know syntactically  , how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use computed property names

just wrap logo +i in `[]`

my guess is it will look like 
`["logo" + i]`

read more here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= paths.length - 1; i++) {
  Polygon.attr({
        ["logo"+i]: {
          d: paths[i],
          stroke: 'red',
          strokeWidth: "15",
          cursor: 'pointer',
          event: 'element:path-click',
          strokeLinecap: "square"
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Note that IE does not support computed property names.

Comment: i think babel should be able to handle it

Comment: Sure, but the question isn't tagged with babel.

Answer (score 0):

Create the object first, then use square brackets to se the `logoX` property:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= paths.length - 1; i++) {
    var attr = {};
    attr["logo"+i] = {
        d: paths[i],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: "15",
        cursor: 'pointer',
        event: 'element:path-click',
        strokeLinecap: "square"
    };

    Polygon.attr(attr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for the dynmaic object literal, you could change the for loop a bit from

```
for (var i = 0; i <= paths.length - 1; i++) {
//                 ^              ^^^
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    Polygon.attr({
        [logo + i]: {
            d: paths[i],
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: "15",
            cursor: 'pointer',
            event: 'element:path-click',
            strokeLinecap: "square"
        }
    });
}
```